# How do I replace a string in a parent page from a JS created childpage?

Tags: javascript, replace

I am creating a dynamic list with JS

```
var obj = JSON.parse(Agent212);
var i;
var serie = "Agent212";
for (i = 0; i < obj.strips.length; i++) {
    if (obj.strips[i].Collectie == "0") {
        document.write("<li><a onclick='newPage(" + obj.strips[i].Nummer + "," + serie + ")' style = 'color:orange'>" + obj.strips[i].Nummer + " - " + obj.strips[i].Titel + "</a></li>");
    }
    else if (obj.strips[i].Collectie == "2") {
        document.write("<li><a onclick='newPage(" + obj.strips[i].Nummer + "," + serie + ")' style = 'color:red'>" + obj.strips[i].Nummer + " - " + obj.strips[i].Titel + "</a></li>");
    }
    else {
        document.write("<li><a class='ToHide' onclick='newPage(" + obj.strips[i].Nummer + "," + serie + ")'><strike>" + obj.strips[i].Nummer + " - " + obj.strips[i].Titel + "</strike></a></li>");
    }
}
```

when I click on an item in the list, I create a childpage

```
 function newPage(StripNum, SerieNaam) {
     var obj = JSON.parse(SerieNaam);
     var i;
     var x = StripNum;
     for (i = 0; i < obj.strips.length; i++) {
         if (obj.strips[i].Nummer == x) {
             if (obj.strips[i].Collectie == 0) {
                 var myWindow = window.open();
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<html>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<head>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/W3CSS.css">');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<scr' + 'ipt>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('function windowClose(){');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('window.close();}'); **
                 myWindow.document.writeln('function ToevoegenVerzameling(){'); **
                 myWindow.document.writeln('window.alert("toegevoegd aan verzameling");');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('window.close();');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('}');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('</scr' + 'ipt>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('</head>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<body>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<div class="w3-container w3-display-topmiddle">');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<div class="w3-card-16 w3-round-xlarge" style="width:100%">');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<a onclick="windowClose();"><center><img src="' + obj.strips[i].Link + obj.strips[i].Nummer + '.jpg"></center></a>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<div class="w3-container w3-margin-top">');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<center><B>Nummer: </B><I>' + obj.strips[i].Nummer + '</I></center>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<center><B>Titel: </B><I>' + obj.strips[i].Titel + '</I></center>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('<center><button onclick="ToevoegenVerzameling()" class="w3-btn w3-light-grey w3-border w3-border-black w3-round-xlarge w3-margin-top w3-margin-bottom" style="width:100%"><h2><b>Toevoegen</b></h2></button></center>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('</div>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('</div>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('</div>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('</body>');
                 myWindow.document.writeln('</html>');
             }
```

all of the above does work, but know I want to ad a replace function to `ToevoegenVerzameling()`.

I've tried with adding this piece of code.

```
myWindow.document.writeln('if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed){');
myWindow.document.writeln('var str = "<li><a onclick='
    newPage(" + obj.strips[i].Nummer + ", " + serie + ")
    ' style = '
    color: orange '>" + obj.strips[i].Nummer + " - " + obj.strips[i].Titel +"</a></li>";');
myWindow.document.writeln('str.replace("<a onclick='
        newPage(", " < a class = 'ToHide'
            onclick = 'newPage(");'); myWindow.document.writeln('str.replace("style = '
            color: orange '>", "><\strike>");'); myWindow.document.writeln('str.replace("</a>", "</strike></a>");}');
```

But I can't get it to work, Were am I making a mistake in this?

Comment: Do you want the DOM to update when the `Array` changes in code?

Comment: No the Dom doesn't need to be updated.It's just temporary, this is only for when I'm on the road. The JSON file will be updated manually when I'm at home.